# Am I understanding the reduced group C*-algebras correctly?

Tags: operator-algebras

Let $G$ be a group and $\mathbb{C}G$ be its group algebra. $\mathbb{C}G$ contains finite linear combinations of group elements of $G$. Let $C^{*}_{r}(G)$ be the reduced group C*-algebra. Let $a, b\in \mathbb{C}$, $g\neq h\in G$. If I understand correctly, $||ag+bh||^{2}_{r}\leq|a|^{2}+|b|^{2}$ by triangle inequality, and consider $(ag+bh)$ act on the identity $e$, which equals to $ag+bh$, and the norm square of $(ag+bh)(e)$ is less than or equal to the norm square of $ag+bh$. But norm square of $(ag+bh)(e)$ is just $|a|^{2}+|b|^{2}$, so the norm square of $ag+bh$ is just $|a|^{2}+|b|^{2}$. Is that correct? Am I understand the concept of reduced group C* norm correctly?

Comment: Do you define the reduced group C*-algebra via the left or via the right regular representation?

Comment: I am using left regular representation.

Comment: Why is $\|ag + bh\|_r^2 \le |a|^2 + |b|^2?$ You have $\|ag + bh\| \le |a| + |b|$ so squaring yields $\|ag+bh\|^2 \le (|a|+|b|)^2$ which is strictly larger than the bound you have!

Comment: Yes, you are right, I made a mistake. I guess the argument that $||ag+bh||^{2}_{r}=|a|^{2}+|b|^{2}$ doesn't valid at all.

Comment: First try to answer the following easier question: If $g \ne e$, what is the norm the element $\|1 + \lambda_g\|$? Is it $2$?

Comment: No, I think it is $\sqrt{2}$, because you need to take the square root of the inner product of the vectors.